# CSV to DataMapper Import

Tags: ruby, database-design, activerecord, datamapper, relational-database

This is probably very simple, but I'm quite new to ruby and active record.

I've got a CSV dump of a database which I'm trying to import to a database using DataMapper. I'm having trouble understanding which type of relationships I should define in the models so that it matches what is defined CSV.

Here's what data I've got from the CSV:

```
Stages:
id
staff_id
project_id
job_id
company_id

Projects:
id
company_id

Jobs:
id
project_id
company_id

Client:
id

Staff:
id
```

For example: do stages belong_to projects or is this has_many relationship?

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecord or DataMapper? (these are 2 different things)

Comment: Sorry, I am using DataMapper, but assumed that the relationship types are similar? e.g. one to many etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming client == company. Here an example for ActiveRecord

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staff
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :company, :class => "Client"
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, :class => "Client"
  has_many :stages
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :company, :class => "Client"
  has_many :stages
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, :foreign_key => "company_id"
  has_many :projects, :foreign_key => "company_id"
  has_many :stages, :foreign_key => "company_id"
end

class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stages
end
```

Here an example for DataMapper:

```
class Stage
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :staff
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :company, "Client"
end

class Project
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :company, "Client"
  has n, :stages
end

class Job
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :company, "Client"
  has n, :stages
end

class Client
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :jobs, :foreign_key => "company_id"
  has n, :projects, :foreign_key => "company_id"
  has n, :stages, :foreign_key => "company_id"
end

class Staff
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :stages
end
```

For the import you should do it in a special order:

1. `Client`, `Staff`, because they can exist independent of all other models
2. `Project`, it depends only on `Client`
3. `Job`, depends on `Project` and `Client`
4. `Stage`, depends on `Staff`, `Project`, `Job` and `Client`

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Looks like I was missing the concept of foreign_key and ended up with lots of fields like client_client_id.